# How to store a row into an array in PHP and echo out a certain value of the array?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to query data from a row in a table, store the data into an array, and then echo out a certain value from the array.  Here's the PHP:

```
$receiveuserdata = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM s_users LIMIT 0,1");

$userdata = array();
$index = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($receiveuserdata)) {
    $userdata[$index] = $row;
    $index++;
};
```

I've tried using other posts related to this issue for help, but most are outdated.  Here's my attempt to echo a value from the array:

```
 <h3>Username: <?php echo $userdata[0]; ?></h3>
```

Am I using `$receiveuserdata` incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To retrieve Single row**

You are used to LIMIT 0,1 - so it will retrieve only one row

```
<?php
$receiveuserdata = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM s_users LIMIT 0,1");
if (mysqli_num_rows($receiveuserdata) > 0)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($receiveuserdata);
    $username = $row['username'];
    echo '<h3>Username: '.$username.'</h3>';
}
?>
```

**To retrive multiple rows**

```
<?php
$receiveuserdata = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM s_users");
if (mysqli_num_rows($receiveuserdata) > 0)
{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($receiveuserdata)) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    echo '<h3>Username: '.$username.'</h3>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I intended to only retrieve one row.  This code is to view your profile.

Comment: You are a lifesaver man.  While I figure out how this code works, I just wanna say thank you for fixing my issue!

Answer (score 0):

$row contains the entire MySQL table row. Which means that `$userdata[0]` also contains a row (as an associative array). Using `echo` does not work with arrays. Instead you can use `var_dump` if you want to see what the row is or access the value you need directly: `$userdata[0]['username']` (if you have a column name `username`)

Comment: I've tried `$receiveuserdata = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM s_users LIMIT 0,1");

$userdata = array();
 $index = 0;
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($receiveuserdata)) {
  $userdata[$index] = $row;
  $index++;
 };

$username = var_dump($userdata[0]['Username']);` and `<h3>Username: <?php echo $username; ?></h3>`, and it doesn't work.  Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: `var_dump` does not return anything (by default). It's just used to echo variables (and is used only for debugging). So if you want to see what's in your row, you can do `var_dump($userdata[0])`) but if you want to actually assign the username to a variable, you need to do `$username = $userdata[0]['Username'];`